# My bit-wise swapping isn't working

Tags: c++

I am trying a simple insertion sort. But the swapping I am trying isn't working when I use bit-wise operation.

But when I use another temporary variable the swapping works. When I compile this code I always get some extra 0s.

How can I figure out what is wrong with my code?

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<algorithm>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
*a=*a^*b;
*b=*a^*b;
*a=*a^*b;
}

int main(void)

{
int arr[size];
int i,j,min;

for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    arr[i]=rand()%100;

for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    printf("%d ",arr[i]);
putchar('\n');

for(i=0; i<size;i++)
{
    min=i;
    for(j=i+1;j<size;j++)
        if(arr[j]<arr[min])
            min=j;
    swap(&arr[i],&arr[min]);
}

for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    printf("%d ",arr[i]);
putchar('\n');

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use `std::swap`. Even creating a temporary is usually optimized more than xor-swap, and `std::swap` takes advantage of move semantics.

Comment: As always, what does the debugger say when you break at `swap`?

Comment: If you do decide to stick with your own function, for swapping, may I suggest using pass by reference, instead of pass by pointer?

Comment: @chris - i have used std::swap and int works fine. But i am new to bit-wise operation, that's why i am trying it. But this doesn't work.

Comment: @StefanZuefeldt - I thought i was using call-by-reference. Can you explain it to me. Thank you.

Comment: @bran.stark Yes!  I can try, at least:  Currently, you're passing pointers to the function, and, for each XOR, you're dereferencing the pointers (a total of 3 times each XOR, unoptimized at least).

It is all in the function declaration: using & means you pass the exact original variable, instead of a copy, or a pointer to it.  It saves a bit of assembly.

Also, using the form  x = x ^ y often creates a temporary variable for (y ^ z);  May I also suggest using x ^= y; instead, as it directly puts it in the proper position.

Try this =) :

void swap(int& a, int& b)
{
a^=b;
b^=a;
a^=b;
}

Comment: Your parameters are `int *a, int *b`. To be passed by reference they'd be `int &a, int &b`. This is C++, you should start using them.

Comment: @bran.stark Also, when passing by reference you might encounter the problem noted by Daniel Fischer's answer. 
To correct myself, perhaps a better method than what I said is:
 void swap(int& a, int& b) { int c = a; c^=b; b^=c; c^=b; a = c; }
     This keeps the original location of a, and also creates a temporary value, c.  The only extra overhead should be the cost of the copy to c, and then the copy back to a; which is minimal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In

```
for(i=0; i<size;i++)
{
    min=i;
    for(j=i+1;j<size;j++)
        if(arr[j]<arr[min])
            min=j;
    swap(&arr[i],&arr[min]);
}
```

if `arr[i]` is the smallest array element, you try to swap it with itself, so the two pointers you pass to swap point to the same memory location, hence the xor zeros out that location.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using insertion sort, can I assume this is an exercise?

What do you think `swap` will do when `a` and  `b` refer to the same address? Try it on a piece of paper and you will see where your extra zeros come from.

Comment: Yes, it was just an exercise. I thinks they will make each other zero. Thank you.